# Count of rows in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to retrieve comments from a table Comment which has id, game (a foreign key) and date.

Every time I ask for comments I want to get 3 comments sorted by date for a specified game and I want to know if there is more comments to show later. For that, I've written two functions, the first one returns the three comments:

```
public function getRecentComments($offset,$id) {
    $dql = "SELECT c FROM Comment c 
        WHERE c.game = ?1
        ORDER BY c.date DESC";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->
        createQuery($dql)->
        setParameter(1, (int)$id)->    
        setMaxResults(3)->
        setFirstResult($offset);
    return $query->getResult();
```

And the second one returns the number of comments I could get later. The reason of this function is wehter show a button "More comments" or not. This is the second function:

```
public function moreComments($offset,$id) {

    $dql = "SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM Comment c
        WHERE c.game = ?1
        ORDER BY c.date DESC";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter(1, (int)$idPartido)
        ->setFirstResult($offset+3)    
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $query;
}
```

But the second function doesn't work for the next error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException' with message 'No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.

Which I think it is due to use setFirstResult and count().

So, I've used

```
public function moreComments($offset,$id) {

    $dql = "SELECT c FROM Comentario c
        WHERE c.partido = ?1
        ORDER BY c.fecha DESC";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter(1, (int)$idPartido)
        ->setFirstResult($offset+3)    
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return sizeof($query);
}
```

Which obviously is bad written because I shouldn't get the data for only a count. How could I write the second function correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will only be using MySQL, then you can take advantage of its [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function.

This will require using native queries, which will most likely hinder your ability to use a DB other than MySQL, but it works quite well in my experience.

I have used something like the following with great success.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

public function getRecentComments($offset, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Comment c 
        WHERE c.game = ?
        ORDER BY c.date DESC
        LIMIT ?,3";
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Comment', 'c');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'game_id', 'game_id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'date', 'date');
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($dql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameters(array(
      (int)$id,
      (int)$offset
    ));
    $results = $query->getResult();

    // Run FOUND_ROWS query and add to results array
    $sql = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS foundRows';
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('foundRows', 'foundRows');
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $foundRows = $query->getResult();
    $results['foundRows'] = $foundRows[0]['foundRows'];

    return $results;
}
```

After getting the results array from the above function, I extract the 'foundRows' element to a separate variable, unset it (i.e., `unset($results['foundRows'])`), and then continue using the array as normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It helped me a lot. However, I will be using postgresql very soon.

Comment: I think you can use your existing second query, but replace `getSingleScalarResult()` with `getScalarResult()`. Or wrap your second query in a try/catch block to catch the exception;if an exception is thrown, then you know there are no more comments.