# Get total number of rows by using 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS' and Doctrine NativeQuery

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a simple query which selects entities and uses limit statement. I am using Doctrine NativeQuery because I have FIELD() function in sql query, and I need a collection of objects as a result.
That query works.

However I need also a total number of records, so I use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the first query. After the first gets the result I create another ResultSetMapping, another $nativeQuery, execute `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows` and I keep getting total number of '1'.

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$rsm->addEntityResult('\\MyCompany\\Administration\\Domain\\Model\\Applicant\\Applicant', 'a');

$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'first_name', 'firstName');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'last_name', 'lastName');

$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM recruitment_applicant ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,15,8,17,2,1,16,9,7,11,6,10,12,13,14,18)', $rsm);

$result = $query->getResult(); // this result is ok



$sqlCountRows = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows";

$countRowsRsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$countRowsRsm->addScalarResult('found_rows', 'foundRows');

$countRowsQuery = $this->em->createNativeQuery($sqlCountRows,$countRowsRsm);

$rowsCount = $countRowsQuery->getResult();

$total = $rowsCount[0]['foundRows']; // result is '1' when it should be '16'
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477814/count-of-rows-in-doctrine-2?lq=1) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have to use native query. `FIELD()` is really very easy to implement as a custom DQL function:

   1. Read [DQL User Defined Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) and [How to Register Custom DQL Functions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) on Doctrine/Symfony documentation.
   2. `FIELD()` implementation:

      ```
      use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
      use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
      use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser; 
      use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

      class Field extends FunctionNode
      {
          private $field = null;
          private $values = array();

          public function parse(Parser $parser)
          {
              $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
              $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

              $this->field = $parser->arithmeticPrimary();

              while (count($this->values) < 1 || $parser->getLexer()->lookahead['type'] !== Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS) {
                  $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
                  $this->values[] = $parser->arithmeticPrimary();
              }

              $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS); 
          }

          public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
          {
              $values = array();
              foreach ($this->values as $value) {
                  $values[] = $value->dispatch($sqlWalker);
              }

              return sprintf('FIELD(%s, %s)', $this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker), implode(', ', $values));
          }
      }
      ```
2. You won't event need a count query. However, if you'd need `COUNT(*)` query you can easily clone your original query and use [`CountWalker`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.Pagination.CountWalker.html) to create count query from select query.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what might be a cause of the problem: Symfony2 profiler, queries section, shows total of 22 queries executed. My first query gets run third in a row and my second query, the one to return the number of rows gets executed 13th.
`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` works if `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` is run  immediately after the first query.