# General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations when filtering with a non-ASCII character

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have a list page where I filter some data and show results, using the Symfony framework. When I put special characters on these filters, for example `ì`, I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(DISTINCT c0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM campaigns c0_ WHERE c0_.title LIKE '%ì%'':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: It then tells you exactly. `Illegal mix of collations`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've attempted to edit your question to more specifically describe the problem that you're having, and have edited the title to include the specific error message. Hopefully I haven't changed the meaning of your post - feel free to edit it further if I have got anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine does not support count function till now.

take a look at 
[Count Rows in Doctrine QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder/27081826)
 
and 
[Count of rows in Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477814/count-of-rows-in-doctrine-2)